# Subtracting bigint timestamp in postgreSQL but not getting exact answer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two columns which have timestamps in Bigint for example "1480083350667" and I need to subtract it:

The script which i am using right now is:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP((employee_reply_timestamp - matched_log_timestamp)/1000), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS reaction_time
```

Where "employee_reply_timestamp" and "matched_log_timestamp" i.e. are two bigint timestamps. If i run this query i am getting the answer which looks something like this `1970-01-01 01:06:58` which is not correct.

I am looking for an answer which can give me the days, hours, minutes and 
seconds difference between the two bigint timestamps.

It would be great if someone can give me the solution and thanks in advance.

Comment: `(TO_TIMESTAMP((employee_reply_timestamp - matched_log_timestamp)/1000))::interval AS reaction_time
` ?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably are looking for interval, like:

```
select 
TO_TIMESTAMP(employee_reply_timestamp/1000)
 - 
TO_TIMESTAMP(matched_log_timestamp/1000)
AS reaction_time
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i am getting this error "cannot cast type bigint to interval"

Comment: and also like this "cannot cast type timestamp with time zone to interval"

Comment: @ChandrasenDRajashekar edited to simplify the syntax. does this work?..

Comment: I have one more question!! 
If i use your query i am getting answers like this "2 days 31:09:34.607843"

Comment: If i have understood correctly it means 2 days and 31 hrs right? According to logic it should come as 3 days and 6 hrs or something right?

Comment: I did upvoted but its not showing since i am new to stack overflow and i need atleast 15 reputation to do so itseems!!

Comment: Okay sounds great!!

Comment: @ChandrasenDRajashekar I could only make an ugly workaround for this. Maybe somebody will help - asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41247289/postgres-normalise-interval-output

Comment: @ChandrasenDRajashekar use justify_interval() for it