# Postgres "normalise" interval output

Tags: postgresql

Answering [simple question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243907/subtracting-bigint-timestamp-in-postgresql-but-not-getting-exact-answer/41244074) I was asked how to "convert" `2 days 31:09:34` to `3 days 07:09:34`. I can't come up with anything less ugly then performing one more time difference, like here:

```
t=# with a as (
  select cast('2 days 31:09:34.607843' as interval) i
)
select i, now() +i -now() wheel,i+interval '1 minute'
from a;
           i            |         wheel          |        ?column?
------------------------+------------------------+------------------------
 2 days 31:09:34.607843 | 3 days 07:09:34.607843 | 2 days 31:10:34.607843
(1 row)
```

Time: 0.232 ms

Please show me the right way to "translate" `'25 hours'::interval` to `'1 day 1 hour'::interval`

Comment: `now() + '1 day'::interval + '1 hour'::interval` is the ugliest way I can think of :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`justify_interval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
with a as (
  select cast('2 days 31:09:34.607843' as interval) i
)
select justify_interval(i)
from a;
```

Output

```
    justify_interval
------------------------
 3 days 07:09:34.607843
(1 row)
```